# How to generate report in Calabash-android

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash

How do we generate reports in calabash android ? I looked in to "The cucumber recipe" book on how to generate report. But that didn't help me completely.
I want to generate report on why login failed :
For eg :
1) User enter valid credential and tries to Login
2) But, Login fails due to server_error/user_not_found or some exceptions . I get error xml/ statusCode from server when login fails.

How to generate report using that xml/status code in calabash ?
Please help !!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this command to execute your test:

```
calabash-android run <apkfile>.apk --format html --out reports.html
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, there's not much documentation around the syntax of these options to be passed. I'd mark this as "Answered" if I could.

Comment: I'm getting an "invalid options" error whenever I run calabash-android with these flags. Anyone know of a fix or work around?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%
date = Time.now.strftime('%m_%d-%H:%M:%S')
default_report = "./reports/output_#{date}.html"
default_rerun = "./rerun.txt"
%>

common: NO_STOP='1'
rerun_out: -f rerun -o <%= default_rerun %>
html_report:  -f html -o <%= default_report %>

run:  -p common -p rerun_out -p html_report
```

Here is my calabash-android profile config, you can put it in ./.config/cucumber.yml file under your calabash android project.
using the following command will export the test result into a rerun.txt file and a ./reports/output_#{date}.html file at the same time:

```
calabash-android run *.apk -p run
```

Answer (score 0):

For HTML report

```
> calabash-android run <apkfile>.apk --format HTML --out
```

For JSON report

```
> calabash-android run <apkfile>.apk --format JSON --out
```

These are the otehr formats in cucumber,

- Pretty
- Progress
- Usage
- JUnit
- Rerun

Read more from here: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#reports

Answer (score 0):

For *HTML* report use the following:

calabash-android run ${APKFile} -f html -o test-result.html